# Setting cookie domain in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm migrating from ASP.NET MVC to .NET Core. My web app is located at example.com. I have a WordPress site at [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and I want the .AspNetCore.Identity.Application cookie to be available at that subdomain. I used to be able to do this by setting the cookie domain to .example.com in Startup.Auth.cs, but I can't figure out how to do it in .NET Core. Setting the cookie domain in `services.AddAuthentication()` has no effect. Here's my `Startup` class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("Cors1", builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .WithMethods("GET");
        }));
        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("Cors2", builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("https://www.example.com")
                   .WithMethods("POST");
        }));
        
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<int>>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        
        // This has no effect:
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                options.Cookie.Name = "LoginCookie";
                options.Cookie.Domain = ".example.com";
            });
        
        services.Configure<PasswordHasherOptions>(options => options.CompatibilityMode = PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode.IdentityV2);

        services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "resources");

        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options => {
            var cultures = new[]
            {
                new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                new CultureInfo("fr")
            };
            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US", "en-US");
            options.SupportedCultures = cultures;
            options.SupportedUICultures = cultures;
        });

        // I don't see a .MyApp.Session cookie
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = ".MyApp.Session";
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
        
        services.AddOptions();

        // Add our Config object so it can be injected
        services.Configure<SmtpConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("AppConfiguration:SmtpConfig"));
        // ... bunch of others
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            await next();                

            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 400)
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/Error/HttpError400");
                return;
            }
            else if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/Error/HttpError404");
                return;
            }
        });

        app.UseHsts();

        var supportedCultures = new[] { "en-US", "fr" };
        var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions().SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
            .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
            .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);

        app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);


        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors();

        app.UseSession();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        // This seems to do nothing
        //app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.Use(next => context =>
        {
            string path = context.Request.Path.Value;

            if (
                string.Equals(path, "/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                string.Equals(path, "/index.html", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                // The request token can be sent as a JavaScript-readable cookie, 
                // and Angular uses it by default.
                var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
                context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken,
                    new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = false });
            }

            return next(context);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you need to set the SameSiteMode to Lax

Comment: @Ovi Nope, .AspNetCore.Identity.Application is already Lax.

Comment: Whether you are using DataProtection or not? From the document:[Share authentication cookies among ASP.NET apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-3.1), we can see that when share authentication cookies with ASP.NET Core Identity, Data protection keys and the app name must be shared among apps, please check it.

Comment: @ZhiLv Thank you! That pointed me in the right direction. I was able to set the cookie domain using `services.ConfigureApplicationCookie()`